# Determining if a line of code is valid based on certain criterion

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Given a line of code, I need to determine if it is valid based on certain criterion.

1. If the line contains any special keywords. A keyword starts with a dollar sign. For instance, `$SREAD` is a keyword here

   ```
   tempval = $SREAD(13,"B14.OATEMP");
   ```
2. I need to get a number of parameters inside the method consisting the keyword. The parameter count is then compared with a constant value inside the application.

What is the easiest way to determine the validity here?

Comment: You have to implement a parser, even that small example uses an assignment, a "function call" and both string and integer parameters. If interpreter you'll use to execute that expression supports run-time compilation you can use it to validate it. You can't do a true validation with a plain regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\$keyword\(([^,\)]+,?)+\)
```

**UPDATED**: and your code:

```
var inputString = "tempval = $keyword(13,\"B14.OATEMP\");";
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, "\".*?\"", "\"\"");

var count = 0;

if (Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"\$keyword\(([^,\)]+,?)+\)"))
    count = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\$keyword\(([^,\)]+,?)+\)")[0]
                 .Groups[1].Captures.Count;
```

Comment: I don't think this would work for the following example: `$SREAD(13,"B14,OATEMP")` (with an embedded comma).

Comment: The OP really needs to develop a grammar and a parser, not use regexes.